# How do I redirect to user dashboard in React FROM express after authenticating with passport

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, mern

I am building an app using the MERN stack and using Passport-local for authentication, express router in the backend, and React router in the front end. React runs on port 3000 and express on port 5000. I am using CORS and localhost:5000 as the proxy server in package.json of react.

In the login page at localhost:3000/login, once the user submits the info and clicks submit I get the request at the backend and it is authenticated by passport without any errors.

However, I can't redirect the user to localhost:3000/dashboard.

How do I redirect the user to a different page in React FROM Express?
How can I use express routes to change the React URL?

Answer (score -1):

**First**, After getting authenticate on the backend, you should send some kind of token to the frontend. so that for further requests that logged in user can be authenticated. Here token will save encrypted data for authentication purposes like the JWT token.

**Second**, When you send the token and success response only then you redirect the user to the Dashboard.

**Third**, Dashboard will be a different controller in node js and when that authenticated user asked for dashboard then you need to send that token from the frontend in the headers of your API, so that backend can identify the user that Is user authenticated or not.

You can check about JWT (json web token) [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken). It is a NPM module.